# How to solve null object reference

Tags: android

This is my code, where the problem comes up.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.login:
            String nama = user.getText().toString();
            String sandi = pass.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin().execute(nama,sandi);
            break;
 }
```

and then this is my code on the AttemptLogin()

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    boolean failure = false;
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;
        String username = args[0] ;
        String password = args[1];
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
             ...etc
            }
```

and this is the LogCat,

[LogCat : null object reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlKvn.jpg)

So, I want get the String from onClick(), and pass the value to the doInBackground() on attemptLogin(). What is the solution about it?
I'm sorry, it's newbie's question, please help us
Thank you so much for your atention :)

Comment: Have you initialized `user` and `pass` fields properly?

Comment: Please update your question to include the code where you initialize user, pass, etc. This will require that you include your Activity class as a whole so we can examine it for you and suggest solutions.

Comment: @HelloWorld thanks for your response, problem solved, I didn't called the right id on my String's variable.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla Thank you, yeah I has checked again my activity class (login.java), and I've found the wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your error the problem seems to be in the:

```
String nama = user.getText().toString();
String sandi = pass.getText().toString();
```

in this point your object "user" or "pass" is NULL,
please check your oncreate method

If you are in Activity then

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .....
        .....
        EditText user= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.**XXXXXXX**); //error here 
        EditText pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.**YYYYYYY**); //error here 
        .....
        .....

}
```

Else if you are in Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


             .....
        .....
        EditText user= (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.**XXXXXXX**); //error here 
        EditText pass= (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.**YYYYYYY**); //error here 
        .....
        .....

        return view;

    }
```

Comment: @VishweshJainkuniya and DaniloCalzetta thank you very much guys, thank you for your experiece in android, and suggest me a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check null Condition for the username and password put it on if condition
2. if(user != null){
   String nama = user.getText().toString();

}

Comment: thanks alot for your suggest, I've appreciate for your solution.